# How to convert a list as the keys of a nested dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, key

I would like to convert my_list as the keys of the dictionaries that are nested in nested_list. Please see lists below:

**I currently have:**

```
my_list = ['Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3']

nested_list = [{'Age': '12', 'Height': '160'}, {'Age': '20', 'Height': '170'}, {'Age': '25', 'Height': '175'}]
```

**Desired output:**

````
final_list = [{'Person1':{'Age':'12', 'Height': '160'}}, {'Person2': {'Age':'20', 'Height': '170'}}, {'Person3': {'Age':'25', 'Height': '175'}}]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by list comprehension:

```
my_list = ['Person1', 'Person2', 'Person3']

nested_list = [{'Age': '12', 'Height': '160'}, {'Age': '20', 'Height': '170'}, {'Age': '25', 'Height': '175'}]

final_list = [{person:description} for person, description in zip(my_list, nested_list)]
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'Person1': {'Age': '12', 'Height': '160'}}, {'Person2': {'Age': '20', 'Height': '170'}}, {'Person3': {'Age': '25', 'Height': '175'}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my function

```
def combine(l, nl):
    final_list = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        final_list += [{l[i]: nl[i]}]
    return final_list
```

so with this function, you can use like this

```
combine(my_list, nested_list)
```

And get result

`[{'Person1': {'Age': '12', 'Height': '160'}}, {'Person2': {'Age': '20', 'Height': '170'}}, {'Person3': {'Age': '25', 'Height': '175'}}]`